# Error in assigning button to Fragment

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments

public class BusinessFragment extends Fragment {
    Button aviation;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.businessfragment, container, false);
}

public void addListenerOnButton1(){
    final Context context = this;

        aviation = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        aviation.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick (View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent (context, Aviation.class);
                startActivity (intent);



                }

                    });

                        }
```

The error underlines the words "this" and "findviewbyid", so i am not able to run the program.
I have googled alot about fragments and intents but could not get a clear answer on how to do it

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type BusinessFragment BusinessFragment.java /Copy of ActionTabs3/src/edu/dartmouth/cs/actiontabs line 28 Java Problem

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from BusinessFragment to Context BusinessFragment.java /Copy of ActionTabs3/src/edu/dartmouth/cs/actiontabs line 26 Java Problem

Comment: i managed to fix all the errors but the button is not opening the new activity Aviation. Below is the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class BusinessFragment extends Fragment {
        Button aviation;

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.businessfragment, container, false);
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton1(){

        aviation = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
         aviation.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){


                public void onClick (View v){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Aviation.class);
                    startActivity(intent);



                    }

                        });

                            }
```

}

I am able to run the application but the button does not open the new activity Aviation.

Comment: Some one help please the application does not run